# Python types: dict of something

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, types, type-hinting

Is there a way to inform python (3.6+) that my attribute is a dict of something?

What I'd like:

```
def classify(self, sentenses: dict(Sentence)):  # <-- dict of Sentence
  for s in sentences:
    a = s.attribute
```

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases), e.g. `Dict[str, Sentence]`

Comment: What are you mapping from and to?

Comment: "a dict of something" is ambiguous. Do you mean `Sentence` as key (with something else concrete or generic as value) or as value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to type as a Dict you have to import Dict from typing. The typing module also offers support for other typing kinds as well. Such as: Tuple, List, and Union. You can use these same types to indicate return values.

```
from typing import Dict


class Sentence:

    def __init__(self):
        self.some_atr = ""
        self.another_atr = ""


def classify(sentences: Dict[str, Sentence]):  # <-- dict of Sentence
  for k, v in sentences.items():
      print(v.some_atr)


s1 = Sentence()
s1.some_atr = "First"

s2 = Sentence()
s2.some_atr = "Second"

sen = {'first': s1, 'second': s2}
classify(sen)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html